# Exchange multiple viewmodels in a single _Layout

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm asking to see if it's possible to swap multiple viewmodels inside a single layout.  For exmample: let's say I have three models: people, cats, and dogs.  Say I bind the people model to a _Layout view to display their names, along with a dog and cat button.  To see a list of their dogs, I select a dogs button and a dog modelview displays in a partial view.  I select a cats button and a cat modelview displays.  I can get the models into the _Layout because of the relationship between the tables using EF Core and a Repository pattern, but I can't figure out how to get different models into a partial view nested inside the _Layout.

Keep in mind, the dog and cat example is an oversimplified example.  The reality is, each table is completely different from the other, and are related only by a parent table.

I've been trying to approach this using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with an MVC pattern.  Am I better off using Razor pages?  Any advice is welcome.

Thanks in advance.
Chuck

Comment: As a **View**Model can work for a single View (or partialView), can't you use a `PartialViewNameViewModel` in wich you have your `people`, `cat` and `dog` models?

Comment: A _layout should be Model independent. A layout should represent common html/scripts/css between pages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

Multiple models cannot be registered in the same view, but if the models have relationships,you could using the parent related model.Or you could make these models in a ViewModels.It could depend on your model design.

And for how to display the cats or dogs.One way did on client side,is that you could put them in one partial view and use js to add or remove the style `display:none` which could display the data or not.The other way did on server side,is that you could put the data in two partial views.Each button click could render the specific partial view.

Here I give a demo about how to meet your requirement by client side:

Model:

```
public class People
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string peepleName { get; set; }
    public List<Cats> Cats { get; set; }
    public List<Dogs> Dogs { get; set; }
}

public class Cats
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string catName { get; set; }
}

public class Dogs
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string dogName { get; set; }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
@inject MvcCore3_1.Data.MvcCore3_1Context _context
@{
    var model = _context.People.Include(p => p.Cats).Include(p => p.Dogs).FirstOrDefault();
}
<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @Html.Partial("part", model)
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>
<script>
    function ShowCat() {
        if (document.getElementById('cats').style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('cats').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('dogs').style.display = 'none'
        } else {
            document.getElementById('cats').style.display = 'none'
        }
    }
    function ShowDog() {
        if (document.getElementById('dogs').style.display == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('dogs').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('cats').style.display = 'none'
        } else {
            document.getElementById('dogs').style.display = 'none'
        }
    }
</script>
```

PartialView named part.cshtml in `Views/Shared` folder:

```
@model People
@Model.peepleName
<br />
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="ShowCat()">cat</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ShowDog()">dog</button>
<table id="dogs" style="display:none">
    @foreach (var dog in Model.Dogs)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@dog.id</td>
            <td>@dog.dogName</td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
<table id="cats" style="display:none">
    @foreach (var cat in Model.Cats)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@cat.id</td>
            <td>@cat.catName</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Result:

[image]